# Stop scrolling once a certain element ends

Tags: html, css

```
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 3000px; background: pink">1</div>
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 1200px; background: yellow">2</div>
</body>
```

Since the second element is shorter than the first one, the browser will normally continue scrolling until it reaches the end of the page, and thus the end of the first element. Is there any way to make the browser stop vertical scrolling once it reached the end of the second element instead, even though the page is longer?

[(fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/WFrSs/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just nest them in a parent div with overflow: hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/WFrSs/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <div style="width: 100%; height:1200px; overflow: hidden">
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 3000px; background: pink">1</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 50%; height: 1200px; background: yellow">2</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS (or in the `style` attribute) you can have `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;` on the first element, and `margin-left: 50%;` on the second (to give the first some space). Then style the container with `overflow: hidden`, in this case the `<body>` element.

This will only work if the first element is always the bigger one though.